# Helicon Zoo Sinatra Static Files

Tags: iis, sinatra

CSS isn't working corectly on IIS 7.5 using Helicon Zoo and Sinatra.

Here is the directory structure:

```
welcometo
 --public
  --styles
   --welcometo.css
```

I tested my site using Webrick and it works perfectly.

When I go to localhost:4567/styles/welcometo.css, the style sheet is displayed in the web browser.

When I go to the IIS site /styles/welcometo.css I get this error:

```
Try this:
get '/public/styles/welcometo.css' do
    "Hello World"
end
```

I copied the web.config from [Helicon Zoo's Sinatra page](http://www.helicontech.com/zoo/usage/ruby-sinatra.htm). Here is the Static files section:

```
<!-- Send static files through IIS -->
<rewrite>
    <rules>
            <rule name="Avoid Static Files" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="^(?!public)(.*)$" ignoreCase="false" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="true">
                        <add input="{APPL_PHYSICAL_PATH}" pattern="(.*)" ignoreCase="false" />
                        <add input="{C:1}public\{R:1}" matchType="IsFile" />
                    </conditions>
            <action type="Rewrite" url="public/{R:1}" />
                </rule>
        </rules>
</rewrite>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We forget to include the web.config example for /public folder, sorry. You can see this example on the page for Ruby on Rails installation here: [Ruby on Rails (2.3.x and 3.x.x) on IIS](http://www.helicontech.com/zoo/usage/ruby-on-rails.htm)
Please put this web.config file into the /public folder:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <handlers>
                <!-- 
                This disables Helicon Zoo handler and makes IIS processing static
                files directly.
                -->
                <remove name="rails.project#x64" />
                <remove name="rails.project#x86" />
        </handlers>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: This works...but the I had to change the "remove name" sections from rails.project to sinatra.project.  Thank you!